# configuring an HTML table

Tags: html-table, css-tables

For a school assignment I have to revamp a website.  I've been trying to make a table to include an image and buttons beside the image.  I have the table set so the image (if you think of this an excel spreadsheet) is in A1, and A1 is as tall as B1, B2, and B3.  So I want to have the large cell for the image and 3 cells, or rows rather, beside that to use as buttons.

I can't figure out how to do this, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm getting right what you are trying to achieve, I guess you should include *rowspan* attribute in one of the td tags (A1 cell).

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Picture Here</td>
    <td>Button1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Button2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Button3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: That's what i wanted.  Thanks!

Comment: Also is there a way to do this with columns?  I tried colspan but it didn't do what i wanted.  I have a table with pictures, the table is 3 wide but the top row only has 2 pictures, I'm trying to center those in the the table, so the center of the 1st picture is right above the split in the 2 below it.  with colspan all i can do is choose the columns to span across and that doesn't work.

Comment: @TracyOlsen Hint: You should select the answer that solved your issue as a correct answer. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to read up on the 'rowspan' attribute for <table>